# WP7 - drag/drop of objects created from a DataTemplate within Canvas

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop, datatemplate

***At a glance:***
My app displays an ItemsControl containing a Canvas as its ItemsPanel. The ItemsControl is bound to a collection of objects, each having Left/Top/Width/Height properties. A DataTemplate is used to generate rectangles that are rendered in the Canvas and positioned correctly (binding on the Left and Top properties).
How can I implement drag/drop to move these rectangles around the Canvas?

***Background for my question:***
My WP7 app displays a "CanvasItemsControl" defined as follows:

```
public class CanvasItemsControl : ItemsControl
    {
        public string XBindingPath { get; set; }
        public string YBindingPath { get; set; }

        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            FrameworkElement contentitem = element as FrameworkElement;
            if (XBindingPath != null && YBindingPath != null)
            {
                Binding xBinding = new Binding(XBindingPath);
                Binding yBinding = new Binding(YBindingPath);
                if (contentitem != null)
                {
                    contentitem.SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, xBinding);
                    contentitem.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, yBinding);
                }
            }
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        }
    }
```

and used in XAML as follows:

```
<hh:CanvasItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TheItemsControl"
   Style="{StaticResource CanvasItemsControlStyle}"
   ItemsSource="{Binding AllObjects}"
   XBindingPath="Left" YBindingPath="Top" />
```

This is the style for the CanvasItemsControl:

```
<Style x:Key="CanvasItemsControlStyle" TargetType="local:CanvasItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ObjectTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter> 
</Style>
```

And this is the DataTemplate I use to render my class:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ObjectTemplate"  >
        <Border Background="{Binding Brush}" 
                Width="{Binding Width}"
                Height="{Binding Height}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The source of the CanvasItemsControl is a collection of objects that have the properties Left, Top, Width, Height, Brush, etc.

***My question***
As you can see, the end result is, as you add items to the AllObjects collection, each object gets rendered and positioned correctly in the canvas. Now I need to drag/drop/move these objects around the canvas. What approach would you advise me to use to implement drag/drop? Can you please guide me through the process?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to my question (at least the best one in my opinion):

1) Use of a regular Canvas as opposed of a custom control inherited from Canvas.
2) Use of a user control taking the data context (the instance of my business entity) via constructor
3) The binding between the Left/Top properties of my business class and the Canvas.Left/Top is declared at the UserControl level.
4) Use of a custom behavior inheriting from System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior. This behavior is attached to the User Control.

I would like to acknowlege [Calvin Schrotenboer](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/calvin-schrotenboer/0/962/609) and Joe Gershgorin for their immense help.

```
<!--____ The UserControl ____-->
   <UserControl...      Canvas.Left={Binding Left}" Canvas.Top={Binding Top}">
      <Grid.... layout of the UserControl instead of using a DataTemplate/>
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <MyExample:MyMouseDragElementBehavior/>
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   </UserControl>
```

The custom behavior:

```
public class MyMouseDragElementBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public event MouseEventHandler DragBegun;
    public event MouseEventHandler DragFinished;
    public event MouseEventHandler Dragging;

    private Point relativePosition;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(MyMouseDragElementBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.AddHandler(
            UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonDown), false);
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler(
            UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonDown));
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private static int zIndex = 0;

    private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }
        zIndex++;
        Canvas.SetZIndex(AssociatedObject, zIndex);

        StartDrag(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
        if (DragBegun != null)
        {
            DragBegun(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleDrag(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
        if (Dragging != null)
        {
            Dragging(this, e);
        }
    }

    internal void HandleDrag(Point newPositionInElementCoordinates)
    {
        double x = newPositionInElementCoordinates.X - relativePosition.X;
        double y = newPositionInElementCoordinates.Y - relativePosition.Y;

        if (AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            var currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(AssociatedObject);
            var currentTop = Canvas.GetTop(AssociatedObject);
            Canvas.SetLeft(AssociatedObject, currentLeft + x);
            Canvas.SetTop(AssociatedObject, currentTop + y);
        }
    }

    internal void StartDrag(Point positionInElementCoordinates)
    {
        relativePosition = positionInElementCoordinates;
        AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.LostMouseCapture += OnLostMouseCapture;
        AssociatedObject.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp), false);
    }

    internal void EndDrag()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= OnMouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.LostMouseCapture -= OnLostMouseCapture;
        AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler(
            UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp));
    }

    private void OnLostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        EndDrag();
        if (DragFinished != null)
        {
            DragFinished(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, if you have a better solution, please let me know and I will change the accepted answer.